# Is there a punishment for failing a Part-time Job?

Tags: story-of-seasons-trio-of-towns

Sometimes I like to just grab every part time job I know I can do and then go about my business for the day. More often than not, though, I'll forget to actually fill my shipping container with the required items before time is up and I fail the job.

The job NPC does say that this is probably not good, but I'm not noticing anything apparent like Town Link Rank decreasing.

What is the punishment(if any) for failing a Part Time Job?